# Change brightness of an image via uislider and gpuimage filter

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I wrote this code to change the brightness of an UIImage via an UISlider and the GPUImageBrightnessFilter. But every time I'll test it the app crashes.

My code:

```
- (IBAction)sliderBrightness:(id)sender {

    CGFloat midpoint = [(UISlider *)sender value];
    [(GPUImageTiltShiftFilter *)brightnessFilter setTopFocusLevel:midpoint - 0.1];
    [(GPUImageTiltShiftFilter *)brightnessFilter setBottomFocusLevel:midpoint + 0.1];

    [sourcePicture processImage];
}

- (void) brightnessFilter {

    UIImage *inputImage = imgView.image;

    sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
    brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageTiltShiftFilter alloc] init];
    //    sepiaFilter = [[GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter alloc] init];

    GPUImageView *imageView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
    [brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:imageView.sizeInPixels]; // This is now needed to make the filter run at the smaller output size

    [sourcePicture addTarget:brightnessFilter];
    [brightnessFilter addTarget:imageView];

    [sourcePicture processImage];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is your problem - but is it possible you try to run the "Brightness" effect on the image before the previous "Brightness" action completed?

Comment: I can guess what you mean, but can you give me an example please? Maybe it could be the problem.

Comment: [stillImageSource processImage]; takes time. If you run [stillImageSource processImage]; again before the first [stillImageSource processImage]; completed, it may cause some problems (I remember I encountered these problems when I was using GPUImage).

Comment: Maybe it's the problem but I only run [stillImageSource processImage];  one time. Or? (I'm new in developing iOS Apps)

Comment: How do you solve the problem?

Comment: Add an NSLog to sliderBrightness. See how many times you actually run it.

Comment: If I adjust the slider far the runs are more and if I adjust the slider less the runs are less. It runs 3-14 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me make an alternative architectural suggestion. Instead of creating a GPUImagePicture and GPUImageBrightnessFilter each time you change the brightness, then saving that out as a UIImage to a UIImageView, it would be far more efficient to reuse the initial picture and filter and render that to a GPUImageView.

Take a look at what I do in the SimpleImageFilter example that comes with GPUImage. For the tilt-shifted image that's displayed to the screen, I create a GPUImagePicture of the source image once, create one instance of the tilt-shift filter, and then send the output to a GPUImageView. This avoids the expensive (both performance and memory-wise) process of going to a UIImage and then displaying that in a UIImageView, and will be much, much faster. While you're at it, you can use `-forceProcessingAtSize:` on your filter to only render as many pixels as will be displayed in your final view, also speeding things up.

When you have the right settings for filtering your image, and you want the final UIImage out, you can do one last render pass to extract the processed UIImage. You'd set your forced size back to 0 right before doing that, so you now process the full image.

Comment: Thanks for your help Brad. I'm new in xcode and don't really know if the block of code, wich I wrote after your tutorial, is correct. Could you have a look at it? I added it to my question.

Comment: @user3608489 - No, that new code doesn't do what I described. You need to set up your filter and view connections ahead of time, and only adjust the filter settings in your slider method. You're still grabbing a UIImage from a UIImageView, rebuilding your filter chain, and pulling a UIImage from it on every single filter update. Again, look at the SimpleImageFilter example and how it does its tilt shift displayed to the screen.

Comment: Ok, now I think it should be work, if you can help me to solve the 3 error in the slider method (I updated the code in my question). Many thanks for your effort.

Comment: @user3608489 - You didn't define your brightness filter as an instance variable, you made a method called brightness. That's not going to work. You need to make an instance variable if you want to refer to it in that way, and have some kind of setup method that creates and configures this brightness filter.

Comment: Ok, I created an instance variable and now this 2 errors are coming up (updated code in question): 1st error: `No visible @interface for 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter' declares the selector 'setTopFocusLevel:'` 2nd error: `No visible @interface for 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter' declares the selector 'setBottomFocusLevel:'`

Comment: @user3608489 - May I recommend taking the time to read a good tutorial on Objective-C before proceeding further? You've copied and pasted code without understanding how it works, and I can't walk you through every step in this.

Comment: Of course I understand the filter code and the code of the brightnessSlider block too. But I don't know how I can solve the errors which I get.

Comment: @user3608489 - The errors are telling you exactly what's wrong here. Please read them.

Comment: I tried but ... `Duplicate interface definition for class 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter'` and `Cannot find interface declaration for 'setTopFocusLevel', superclass of 'GPUImageBrightnessFilter'`.

Comment: Ok, now I get no more errors. But if I change the UISlider nothing happens. Hope you can help me.